# Problem with using multiple databases in Entity Framework Core using database-first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application, and for it, I am using two databases as two different environment. In my project, I have added both databases for my both databases there is `.edmx` generated with the name but the model class which contain table parameter is generated in only one `.edmx`. If I update in which the class is not generated then the class is move from previous `.edmx` to the updated one.

Can you give me a suggestion what I need to do in that case?

Comment: EF **Core** doesn't work with  `.edmx` files..... those have been deprecated and removed